# JNDI Lookup for EJB failed

Tags: jsf-2, ejb-3.0, jndi

I am developping a maven ear project with netbeans 7.2.1 and glassfish 3.1. 
I want to use stateless EJB Facade into JSF Managed Controller and since the EJB injection did'nt work i am trying to do JNDI lookup. So i copied the following portable JNDI name printed out by glassfish logging:

INFO: EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB AirportFacade: [java:global/com.procc_FLAMS-ear_ear_1.0-SNAPSHOT/FLAMS-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT/AirportFacade, java:global/com.procc_FLAMS-ear_ear_1.0-SNAPSHOT/FLAMS-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT/AirportFacade!com.procc.dao.AirportFacadeLocal]

when i run the project it says that lookup failed!

Error message:

```
SEVERE: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:global/FLAMS-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT/FLAMS-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT/AirportFacade!com.procc.dao.AirportFacadeLocal' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: FLAMS-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT]
```

I don't know why ?

Below is pom headers:

EAR Module:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>   <parent>
    <artifactId>FLAMS</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.procc</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>   </parent>

  <groupId>com.procc</groupId>   <artifactId>FLAMS-ear</artifactId>   <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>   <packaging>ear</packaging>

  <name>FLAMS-ear</name>
```

EJB Module:

> ```
> <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
> <parent>
> <artifactId>FLAMS</artifactId>
> <groupId>com.procc</groupId>
> <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>   </parent>
>
> <groupId>com.procc</groupId>
> <artifactId>FLAMS-ejb</artifactId>
> <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
> <packaging>ejb</packaging>
>
> <name>FLAMS-ejb</name>
> ```

and finally stateless EJB:

> @Stateless public class AirportFacade extends AbstractFacade
>   implements AirportFacadeLocal {
>       @PersistenceContext(unitName = "flams_pu")
>       private EntityManager em;
>
> ```
> @Override
> protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
>     return em;
> }
>
> public AirportFacade() {
>     super(Airport.class);
> } }
> ```

JNDI Lookup in JSF bean:

> @ManagedBean(name="airportController") @ViewScoped public class
>   AirportController extends AbstractController implements
>   Serializable {
>
> ```
> private transient AirportFacade ejbFacade;
>
> public AirportController() {
>     super(Airport.class);
> }
> ```
>
> @PostConstruct
>       public void init() {
>
> ```
>     super.setFacade(ejbFacade);
>     if(ejbFacade==null){
>         try {
>             Context ctx = new InitialContext();
>             ejbFacade = (AirportFacade)ctx.lookup("java:global/com.procc_FLAMS-ear_ear_1.0-SNAPSHOT/FLAMS-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT/AirportFacade!com.procc.dao.AirportFacadeLocal");
>         } catch (NamingException ex) {
>             Logger.getLogger(AirportController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```